# How to improve my preprocessing with opencv for tesseract-ocr?

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, opencv3.0

I'm using tesseract-ocr for recognizing my text (Treating the image as a single word ).

> tesseract ./my_image.jpg stdout -l heb --oem 1 --psm 8

but after passing my preprocessed image to tesseract I get the following message:

**"Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead"**
and the result was an empty string.

The given image is:

[image]

So i decided using **kolorpaint** for **just smoothing the letters' edges as a square shape**, and have passed the the new image with the exact parameters:

> tesseract ./my_image_after_smoothing.jpg  stdout -l heb --oem 1 --psm
>   8

The new image:

[image]

This time i **did NOT get the warning** ,  moreover **tesseract successfully recognized the word** !!

So my questions are:

1. What is the the reason I get this warning?  and how come i don't get it after i have smoothed those edges?
2. Has tesseract failed because of the dpi issue or because of the rough edges? (it's still unclear for me)
3. Does anyone has a simple approach how to smooth the letter's edges easily?
   I noticed here a great algorithm with some complexity in c++ ([algorithm](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/12/07/resampling-smoothing-and-interest-points-of-curves-via-css-in-opencv-w-code/)) looking for something a bit simpler

**Any suggestion/tip is well appreciated!**

Comment: Invert image colors from black-white to whie-black

Comment: Thank you @Dmiitrii Z. :), but i'm still getting an empty string from tesseract after inverting the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is tesseract output after inverting colors and dilating:

> 01°

```
cv::bitwise_not(image, image);

int top = (int) (0.25 * image.rows);
int bottom = (int) (0.25 * image.rows);
int left = (int) (0.25 * image.cols);
int right = (int) (0.25 * image.cols);

cv::copyMakeBorder(image, image, top, bottom, left, right, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(255));

Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT, Size( 2*5 + 1, 2*5+1 ), Point( 5, 5 ) );
dilate(image, image, element);


tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseractAPI = //get tesseract instance

tesseractAPI->SetImage(image.data, image.size().width, image.size().height, image.channels(), (int) image.step1());
tesseractAPI->Recognize(nullptr);
char *extractedText = tesseractAPI->GetUTF8Text();
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the assistance. I have applied the dilation on the original image (first image on the post), but the edges are still jagged. are you sure it worked for you?
because I got totally different result.

Comment: I have also added a bit more whitespace to the inverted image. I have tested that with tesseract 4 LSTM

Comment: I've updated the answer to show all the preprocessing steps

Comment: I have added the white border to the inverted image, and applied the dilation but unfortunately I still get jagged edges. I have posted my python code here:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/D7g85Vz6 
if you'll run it, you can the see edges remain the same.

Comment: Your code snippet works fine for me, can you add the result of it to your question & clarify which tesseract version you're using